# Attaching images to MMS

Tags: android, mms

I am trying to attach an image that is picked from the image gallery to a MMS.

I am using the following code

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {

        Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
        selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(selectedImagePath);
        Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
        sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "some text"); 
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
        sendIntent.setType("image/png"); 
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, ""));
    }
}
```

When I select the image it is redirecting to the MMS application but displaying a toast which says `Sorry you could not attach this image`.

When I tried to email the same image there was no errors thrown. Here is the Logcat output.

```
01-27 16:04:26.485: ERROR/Mms/media(728): IOException caught while opening or reading stream
01-27 16:04:26.485: ERROR/Mms/media(728): java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: /sdcard/6906-lightning.jpg
01-27 16:04:26.485: ERROR/Mms/media(728):     at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:507)
01-27 16:04:26.485: ERROR/Mms/media(728):     at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:345)
01-27 16:04:26.485: ERROR/Mms/media(728):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
```

I want to also know how to insert a pre defined PhoneNumber when the MMS application is opened.

Comment: Can anyone please help me on this? I am in desperate need of the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorted it...

My Mistake. Instead of uri stream i passed the image location.

Solved it by using...

```
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(selectedImageUri.toString()));
```